# Memcached for PHP 5.3

Tags: php, memcached

I have looked everywhere for some clues on how to run the Memcached extension in my WAMP windows development environment (thats right, the **memcached** with an **D** in the end, not memcache).

I already use memcache (without the **D**), but it would be handy to take part of **memcached**'s more extended multiple-server features.

How can I get this up and running?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

memcached uses libmamcached, which -- according to the PHP Windows build team -- doesn't compile on windows. Therefore the extension can't be built either.